# is there any possibility to get the name of a person from facebook with C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Those days I was wondering if I can get a person name from facebook with c# using only the facebook profile link.

For example in my program are 2 textboxes and 1 button. In first text box will be inserted in question person facebook profile and after clicking on a button the name just shows up in the second textbox.

I searched all over the web for something like this but I didn't found too much about this.
Do you think guys this is possible? If yes, how?

Comment: I guess that you could try and scrape the name but I think that the best and most correct thing to do is request it from the Facebook graph. Which would require OAuth and them logging in.

Comment: That can be a possibility... i will think about that:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do this without using `Facebook API`. Check this out. This should help you: https://developers.facebook.com/

This link to be exact: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Hope it helps!